# Minimize area of polygon

Tags: inequality, optimization

Let us consider given $n$ segments with length and tangent($0 < \theta < 90)$. Starts with the origin(i.e. $(0, 0)$), we connect the segments with end to end. And calculate the area between the segments and $x$-axis. The problem is to minimize this area.

I already know the answer; connect the segment with smallest tangent value, but how can I prove it(In algebraic way)?

I apologize for my bad English.

--------Addition---------

[image]

I apologize to make an ambiguity; all segments have different and fixed length and angle. We also choose the arbitrary order to connect. Also, the segments cannot be rotated(i.e. the endpoints are increase both x-coordinate and y-coordinate), and our goal is minimize the area covered by the segments, the x-axis, and the perpendicular line from end of last segment.

Comment: Could you add a drawing of what you mean?

Comment: Every segments have its own length and tangent(angle), and the problem is minimize the area of between the x-axis and connected segments. I can upload picture after 10 minutes about.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are given a bunch of vectors:
$$v_1 = (\ell_1\cos\theta_1,\ell_1\sin\theta_1),
v_2 = (\ell_2\cos\theta_2,\ell_2\sin\theta_2), \ldots
v_n = (\ell_n\cos\theta_n,\ell_n\sin\theta_n)
$$
with $\theta_i \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. You want to find a permutation $\pi$ of them to minimize the area under the polygonal path:
$$u_0 = (0,0), u_1 = u_0 + v_{\pi(1)}, \ldots u_k = u_{k-1} + v_{\pi(k)}, \ldots, u_n = u_{n-1} + v_{\pi{n}}$$
Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: If that is the case, assume you have already renamed the vectors $v_i$ to make the polygon path: $u_k = u_{k-1} + v_k$ (i.e $\pi = id$ ) has minimal area. Consider
what will happen if you exchange the role of vectors $v_k$ and $v_{k+1}$, the change of the area will be proportional to $\ell_k\ell_{k+1}\sin(\theta_{k+1} - \theta_{k})$. In order for the given configuration to have smallest area, this change has to be positive. i.e $\theta_{k+1} > \theta_k$. So the $\theta_k$ for minimal configuration has to be increasing.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Is there any direct method to prove this argument?(something like the rearrangement inequality)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very clear now. Your suggested solution is correct: We should arrange the given vectors ${\bf a}_k=\rho_k(1,\tan\theta_k)$ in order of  increasing $\theta_k$.

*Proof.* Assume that the $\theta_k$ are not increasing with $k$. Then there is a $k$ such that $\theta_k>\theta_{k+1}$. Draw a figure showing this situation. You can then easily see that interchanging ${\bf a}_k$ and ${\bf a}_{k+1}$ leaves most of the polygon unaltered. Only the two vertical strips coming from ${\bf a}_k$ and ${\bf a}_{k+1}$ are affected: We see that a parallelogram spanned by these two nonparallel vectors, hence having positive area, is subtracted.

Since there are only $n!$ ways of ordering the vectors there has to be an optimal ordering.  The above argument shows that an optimal ordering has to have increasing $\theta_k$.